# Kafka Manager not able to connect to brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have 3 brokers (`brker1`, `broker2` and `broker3`), my kafka manger is able connect to `broker2` but not able to connect with remaining two brokers (`broker1` and `broker3`). I restarted `kafka-manager`, `broker1` and `broker3` as well but still not connecting to these 2 brokers.

Note :- kafka is running on 3 brokers

This log I got from `kafka-manage`

```
[error] k.m.a.c.BrokerViewCacheActor - Failed to get broker metrics for BrokerIdentity(3,broker3,9092,9999,false)
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: IP; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.newClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2430) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
```

I am using `kafka-manager-1.3.2.1`

3 brokers(broker1, broker2 and broker3) are running

this is the log I am getting from broker1 (kafka-manager not able to connect to this broker)

```
[2018-05-08 07:10:11,217] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Loading group metadata for topic-1 with generation 27 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-05-08 07:10:11,217] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Loading group metadata for topic-2 with generation 3 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-05-08 07:10:11,217] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,2] in 28 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-05-08 07:10:11,218] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Loading offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,16] (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-05-08 07:10:11,224] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,16] in 6 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-05-08 07:17:53,774] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 4 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error "Connection refused" could indicate there is no process listening on that port, or there is a firewall on that machine blocking that port.

From the machine where kafka-manager runs, can you do `nc broker3 9092` and `nc broker3 9999`? If these two commands "hang" it means it's not just a Kafka Manager problem.

I realize this is an old question, I just came across it by chance as I was looking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to publish JMX PORT/HOST so that Kafka-Manager would be able to discover brokers, those are controlled by below params in broker starter script.

```
Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${ip}
JMX_PORT=9997
```

For more details follow: https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/issues/214